# Change FPS rate of particle simulation

Tags: particles

I am trying to do a particle simulation at 120 fps because I want some slo-mo shots. But I have noticed the changing BLender's fps rate does not change the simulation. I believe it is still being done in 24 fps. Is there any way in which it can be done?